# Excel Formula multiple Index Match and Average the result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

1. I have two index match formulas looking at another excel tab pivot data

INDEX(MATCH())+INDEX(MATCH())

2. Both formulas have IFERROR = 0

IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH()))+IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH()))

3. And overall an IFERROR to return 0

IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH()))+IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH())))

Above works OK.

I now need to average so if the first index match return 30 and the second index match return 20 I need (30+20)=50/2 = 25

If the first index match return 0 and the second index match return 40 I need (0+40)=40/1 = 40
and vice versa

Is there a way to do this which doesn't involve IF(AND(, can AVERAGEIF or IFS be used or something else to keep it simple.

Example of Data Table being used

[image]

Formula

[image]

Thanks Gridlock but your example is missing last match in top formula e.g. if you had this

[image]

put formula in cell G3
=INDEX($M$3:$O$8,MATCH(G$1&$D3,$L$3:$L$8,0),MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0))

Comment: thinking about it wonder I guess I could do a count something like this ? IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH()))+IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH())))
/
COUNT(INDEX(MATCH()))+COUNT(INDEX(MATCH()))

Comment: I think you should upload an image that shows your data because there may be a better calculation formula for it.

Comment: Hi, have added a couple of images, hope they help

Comment: Hi, you say 20 and 10 but i see 30 and 20. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry GridLock your right the first text I wrote was an example I have changed text to match image

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions are separate and unrelated, try this function:

```
=AVERAGE(SUMIF($L$3:$L$7,G1&F3&D3,$M$3:$M$7),SUMIF($L$3:$L$7,G1&F3&E3,$M$3:$M$7))
```

[image]

but I see you have general yearly conditions, so I'll take 2001 as a condition,so let's combination with wildcard in averageif:

```
=AVERAGEIF($L$3:$L$7,G1&"*",$M$3:$M$7)
```

[image]

**Update:--------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Hope it works for you!

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(G$1,LEFT($L$3:$L$6,4))*IF(INDEX($M$3:$O$6,,MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0))=0,OFFSET(INDEX($M$3:$O$6,,MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0)),1,),INDEX($M$3:$O$6,,MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0))))/2
```

in Excel>=2019

```
=AVERAGEIFs(INDEX($M$3:$O$7,,MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0)),$L$3:$L$7,G$1&"*",INDEX($M$3:$O$7,,MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0)),"<>0")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks GridLock, I don't think this will work as it also needs to refer to your ColM 'First4months' as this column can move, i.e. like in index match formula image.

Comment: Hi, Just added an image and formula to original post

Comment: Full formula to go in cell G3 from example image just sent: =INDEX($M$3:$O$8,MATCH(G$1&$D3,$L$3:$L$8,0),MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0))+INDEX($M$3:$O$8,MATCH(G$1&$E3,$L$3:$L$8,0),MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0))

Comment: Oops, am I dizzy? Okay, I'll review it later.

Comment: hi, yours formula is `= index (, match, match)` not `= index (, match)` maybe i don't see this. maybe I sat on the computer for a long time so I couldn't see it. I have understood your problem

Comment: Hi, I hope it works, although it's quite different from the images you put out. I rested a bit later last night.

Comment: Thanks Grid this is very close but it needs to not included 0 or blank e.g. in your example if you do: cellM3=20, M4=10 total = 30/2 = 15 this is correct but if cellM3=0, M4=10 total = 10/1 = 10 at the moment it will show result 5 as it does 10/2

Comment: If you put this formula in to cell G3 it works but it is huge, anyway to make it more simple

Comment: = IF(AND(IFERROR(INDEX($M$3:$O$8,MATCH(G$1&$D3,$L$3:$L$8,0),MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0)),0)<>0,IFERROR(INDEX($M$3:$O$8,MATCH(G$1&$E3,$L$3:$L$8,0),MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0)),0)<>0),(IFERROR(INDEX($M$3:$O$8,MATCH(G$1&$D3,$L$3:$L$8,0),MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($M$3:$O$8,MATCH(G$1&$E3,$L$3:$L$8,0),MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0)),0))/2,(IFERROR(INDEX($M$3:$O$8,MATCH(G$1&$D3,$L$3:$L$8,0),MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($M$3:$O$8,MATCH(G$1&$E3,$L$3:$L$8,0),MATCH($F3,$M$2:$O$2,0)),0))/1)

Comment: I updated the formula a bit,Try this for the time being, I'm going to try tonight to find a better one

Comment: Thanks GridLock unfortunately not on Excel 2019 but Excel 2010.. :-o

Comment: Seems like it is going to be v difficult to get that big formula down into a nice simple script :-(

Comment: @RogerClerkwell I came up with 2 formulas, the first one doesn't work for you?

Comment: Hi, it needs to also look at the value 1 and value 2 columns, like the long formula posted above, and looks like it is including 0 in the divide count

Comment: Thanks for your help on this GridLock

Comment: Ah, I looked out. There is still one case!